# How to edit this return multiple matches VBA code to input matches below?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have this VBA code. It essentially is a vlookup but returns multiple matches. However, it inputs the matches next to the desWs value (“A1”). Goes column by column. How can I edit this to input the data below? Also I would like to be able edit the return matches location as the lookup value will be in “A1” but I would like some matches to go in column A and also column B. This will be done by running this code multiple times with different column numbers to search for on Sheet1.

I have tried editing the code a number of times with no luck. Either it doesn’t input the data down bottom or it doesn’t return all matches. Currently I use an array formula to do this but it slows down my file heavily. Here is the code. Thank you all.

```vb
Sub ReturnMultipleMatches()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow3 As Long, rng As Range, sAddr As String, _
         Val As Range, lCol As Long, desWS As Worksheet, srcWS As Worksheet

    Set desWS = Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set scrWS = Sheets("Sheet1")

    LastRow1 = scrWS.Cells.Find("*",   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastRow3 = desWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 

    For Each rng In desWS.Range("A1")
    
        Set Val = scrWS.Range("A2:AH" &  LastRow1).Find( _
                         rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
        If Not Val Is Nothing Then
            sAddr = Val.Address
            Do
                lCol = desWS.Cells(rng.Row, desWS.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
                desWS.Cells(rng.Row, lCol) = scrWS.Cells(Val.Row, 30)
                Set Val = scrWS.Range("A2:AH" & LastRow1).FindNext(Val)
             Loop While Val.Address <> sAddr
             sAddr = ""
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: "I would like some matches to go in column A and also column B" that's a bit vague though - do you mean each time you run it, it should populate the next column over with  the matches?  So run1 >> ColA , run2 >> ColB etc ?

Comment: @Tim Williams Sorry we’ll start with just underneath. So how do I get the information to appear below?

Comment: Maybe you could show us what you have and what you want instead of trying to puzzle it out from code that does not work?

Comment: What I have is included. That’s the code I have. It looks for the value (“A1”)  on Sheet 3 in column A of sheet 1. Then returns all the matches from the respective 30th column. All the matches are lined up next to each other in the same room. I want the matches below the lookup value.

Comment: I meant all the matches are lined up in the same row

Comment: "It essentially is a vlookup but returns multiple matches" Reading through the code, I can't see it returning anything to be honest. Maybe it would be easier with a snippet of example data and expected result.

Comment: Ok technically `desWS.Cells(rng.Row, lCol) = scrWS.Cells(Val.Row, 30)` is an output at least... So we print whatever is in Sheet1, column "AD" in the first row of Sheet3? Loads of times? I don't get it. "So how do I get the information to appear below?" Below where?

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```vb
Sub ReturnMultipleMatches()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LastRow1 As Long, rng As Range, sAddr As String, cDest As Range, _
         Val As Range, lCol As Long, desWS As Worksheet, srcWS As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrch As Range
    
    Set srcWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set desWS = Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    LastRow1 = srcWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    
    Set rngSrch = srcWS.Range("A2:AH" & LastRow1)
    
    For Each rng In desWS.Range("A1").Cells
    
        Set Val = rngSrch.Find(rng.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not Val Is Nothing Then
            'first empty cell below the value being searched
            Set cDest = desWS.Cells(Rows.Count, rng.Column).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
            sAddr = Val.Address
            Do
                cDest.Value = Val.EntireRow.Cells(30).Value
                Set cDest = cDest.Offset(1, 0) 'next row down
                Set Val = rngSrch.FindNext(Val)
             Loop While Val.Address <> sAddr
             sAddr = ""
        End If
        
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Exactly what I needed. And it’s very easy to adjust the positioning also with the Offset function. Thank you so much Tim!